# How to add month to a date based on value from another columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a PlannedDate and PeriodLength column. I want to have a new column PlannedMonth. The PlannedMonth should have the result set based on PlannedDate and PeriodLength. So, the PlannedMonth I want to get is

```
PlannedMonth is PlannedDate + 0, PlannedDate + 1, ... PlannedDate + (PeriodLength - 1)
```

I have already achieve something similar

```
DECLARE @PeriodLength INT = (SELECT PeriodLength FROM IP WHERE Id = [some_id]),
        @index INT = 1
    WHILE (@index <= @PeriodLength)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            PlannedDate, 
            DATEADD (mm, @index, PeriodStartDate) AS 'PlannedMonth',
            @index
        FROM
            IP
        WHERE 
            Id = [some_id]
    SET @index = @index + 1 
END
```

But the problem with this approach is that I am having multiple tables while I want a single table with all the results.

Comment: Use arecursive CTE. You will get the same result in one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select id, PlannedDate, 0 as ind, PeriodLength
      from ip
      union all
      select id, dateadd(1, month, PlannedDate), ind + 1, PeriodLength
      from cte
      where ind <= PeriodLength
     )
select *
from cte;
```

If you only want one IP, you can add a `where` clause, either in the outer query or in the first subquery.

Answer (score 0):

This is with a temporary table variable.Correct small mistakes if there comes any.

```
     DECLARE @tab table(p_date date,p_month date,@index int)
        DECLARE @PeriodLength INT = (SELECT PeriodLength FROM IP WHERE Id = [some_id]),
                @index INT = 1

            WHILE (@index <= @Perio

dLength)
        BEGIN
            insert into @tab SELECT 
                PlannedDate, 
                DATEADD (mm, @index, PeriodStartDate) AS 'PlannedMonth',
                @index
            FROM
                IP
            WHERE 
                Id = [some_id]
        SET @index = @index + 1 
        END
    select * from @tab
```